# Android Phone Back Button not working Unity

Tags: unity, android

I take an empty gameobject and a script in which I just 
write below code to handle back button in android phone, but 
it's not working.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape)){
            // Escape button pressed
            print("Escape");
}
```

Comment: Is the script with this code attached to an object in the scene? Which object?

Comment: Yes i take empty gameobject , and attached script with this gameobject. Update is executing but its not going to if stament.  i am running game using unityRemote applciation in my phone

Comment: Can you try attaching the script to your Main Camera - or something that takes input?

Comment: Examples I've found seem to use the GetKeyUp method rather than the GetKeyDown method.

Try making the change and see if it works. Android may not send the keydown event.

Comment: What to do with Input Manager ? I don't know about it. I am new in unity

Comment: GetKeyUp also not working

Comment: InputManager is in the menus, it allows you to set the default mapping for control input. it is the part of unity that set the values that you're accessing through the "Input.get..." methods. At this point I'm at a loss. That was the only difference I could see between your code and the tutorials out there. Checking InputManager is my last idea.

Comment: Try this instead (outside the update method): `OnApplicationPause(){print("Escape");}` and let me know how it goes. Also, @Stephan InputManager doesn't have the Escape as a key, it's a built-in keycode (at least it is so in the latest version).

Comment: Another example I've found uses the Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape) for android.  Down and Up might not apply for mobile.

Comment: OnApplicationPause(){print("Escape");} works for editor not for mobile

Comment: if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape)){
            // Escape button pressed
            print("Escape");
} 

This code is working

Problem was i was testing it through unity remote 5.  that's why it was taking input from keyboard not from mobile, When i tested it by making apk its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape)){ 
  // Escape button pressed print("Escape"); 
}
```

This code is working. Problem was i was testing it through unity remote 5. that's why it was taking input from keyboard not from mobile, When i tested it by making apk its working.